# Why std::cin string input asking me for each space

Tags: c++

This week I started studing a text files in C++ and in my exercice I have to do a program that the user enter the lines in the file, but... for each space that the user enters, the program asking the new to user.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    ofstream myfile;
    string answer;

    do{
        cout << "Insert a line in the file[END to finalize]: ";
        cin >> answer;
        myfile.open("example.txt");
        myfile << answer;
        myfile.close();
    }while(answer != "END");
}
```

The result is:

> Insert a line in the file[END to finalize]: **Hello my friend**
>
> Insert a line in the file[END to finalize]: Insert a line in the
>   file[END to finalize]: Insert a line in the file[END to finalize]:

Comment: But what's the problem? Btw, doing so, if the user type END in the first time, then "END" gonna be write in the file

Comment: What's the question? You've somewhat described your bug and it's due to the default delimiter being a space. Consider using `getline` instead then you can move on to the next problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator>>(istream&, string&)` basically grabs the next word.  If you want to grab a whole line, try `std::getline(std::cin, answer);`.

`getline` won't include the newline, though.  Meaning you'll have to do something like `myfile << answer << '\n';` to output them as lines.

BTW, in most cases you'd want to either open the file outside the loop, or open it for appending with something like `myfile.open("example.txt", ios::app);`.  Opening the file in the loop each time like you're doing, i'm pretty sure you position the file pointer at the beginning of the file, so each line you write will overwrite at least the first part of the previous line.

Comment: Yes, it discards the delimiter - by default `\n` [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> answer` will read one word, delimited by whitespace. 
If you want to read a whole line, then use `getline(cin, answer)`